# Iterate over struct Hashmap and add value to another portion of self

Tags: struct, rust, hashmap

Currently I have a struct that looks something like the following:

```
struct foo {
    pending: HashMap<K, V>,
    loaded: Vec<V>,
}
```

I'm trying to write a function that will load all the pending hashmap values into loaded, while deleting any values from pending if they do not meet a certain criterion, this is what I've got right now:

```
pub async fn load(&mut self) {
    let mut rm_vector = Vec::new();
    for (key, value) in self.pending.iter_mut() {
        self.add_to_loaded(value).await.unwrap_or_else( |err| {
            if err == Error::SomeError {
                rm_vector.push(key.clone())
            }
        })
    }
    
    for value in rm_vector {
        self.pending.remove(&value);
    }
}
```

The issue that I am having is that I am getting a second mutable borrow error when calling the first for loop and the if statement right after. I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions how to go about fixing this without cloning the entire hashmap.

Comment: Could you post the actual code ( the relevant parts ). The code you pasted is hard to follow as it is. I see you have `.await` calls but the function itself is not an `async` function nor this is run in an `async` block. Are you trying implement the Future trait for your Struct ?

Comment: ah I forgot to add async to the function declaration. basically add_to_loaded adds a given value to loaded, and throws SomeError and doesn't add to loaded if a certain criterion isn't met. I didn't include add_to_loaded because the function is around 100 lines so it made a little bit more sense to just include the function call.

Comment: Does `add_to_loaded` have a `&mut self` argument?

Comment: @Kitsu yes, it has &mut self and value as params

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you please add the function `add_to_loaded`, the `Error` type and most importantly the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following simplified code to replicate the issue.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo {
    pending: HashMap<String, u32>,
    loaded: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn add_to_loaded(&mut self, v: u32) {
        self.loaded.push(v);
    }
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn load(&mut self) {
        for _ in self.pending.iter_mut() {
            self.add_to_loaded(30);
        }
    }
}
```

The cause I think is both iter_mut() and add_to_loaded(&mut) try to mutable borrow self.

I can think of two ways to go around the problem.

Option A:

Declare the field loaded as RefCell<Vec>. With it, the first parameter of add_to_loaded can be declared as an immutable reference of self and use iter() instead of iter_mut() to iterate the HashMap. There will be no mutable borrows in the for statement. In add_to_loaded, use borrow_mut() to get a mutable reference to modify the loaded field.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Foo {
    pending: HashMap<String, u32>,
    loaded: RefCell<Vec<u32>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn add_to_loaded(&self, v: u32) {
        self.loaded.borrow_mut().push(v);
    }
}
impl Foo {
    pub fn load(&mut self) {
        for _ in self.pending.iter() {
            self.add_to_loaded(30);
        }
    }
}
```

Option B:
Split the two fields and the two methods into two structs.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo {
    pending: HashMap<String, u32>,
}

struct Foo2 {
    loaded: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn load(&mut self, f: &mut Foo2) {
        for _ in self.pending.iter() {
            f.add_to_loaded(30);
        }
    }
}

impl Foo2 {
    fn add_to_loaded(&mut self, v: u32) {
        self.loaded.push(v);
    }
}
```